# Runs only some statements before 'os.system()' is called

Tags: python, function, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm writing a Python program that has a GUI using PyQt5 and that also calls a MATLAB file using os.system(). However, one of the functions I have decides to not execute any PyQt-related statement Before os.system is called. Normal functions like 'print' run before os.system but the others won't. However, it runs them after os.system is called just fine

Ex)

```
def button_clicked(self):
    print("Button Clicked")    #works
    self.label.hide()          #does nothing

    os.system()                #MATLAB called. works

    self.label.hide()          #now works
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening. The really odd things is that the program just seems to ignore everything PyQt-related in the function before os.system, because even if I do the following:

```
def myFunction(self):
    self.label.hide()
    self.label2.hide()
    print("myFunction Called")  

def button_clicked(self):
    self.label.hide()          #does nothing
    self.label2.hide()         #does nothing
    print("Button Clicked")    #works
    self.myFunction()          #does everything in the function unless it's PyQt-related, in this instance, it prints "myFunction Called" and nothing else

    os.system()                #MATLAB called. Works

    self.label.hide()         #now works
    self.label2.hide()        #now works
```

Is os.system always executed first in a function or something? But then that wouldn't explain why things like 'print' are working.

Comment: please provide  a  [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system()` is ***blocking***. This means that it will not return until the command that it called actually returns (eg.: the program quits).

In terms of event driven systems like Qt, this is a *terrible* mistake, because a blocking function prevents the event loop to process **all events**: not only those that come from the system (such as keyboard or mouse interaction) but also its own events, most importantly the *drawing* of widgets.

Your labels are actually hidden to the point of view of Qt (you could try a `print(self.label.isVisible())`), but since you're calling `os.system` right after that, Qt has had no time to *visually update* the widgets in order to reflect that.

While normally threading (with python's own modules or Qt's QThread, depending on the requirements, or even QRunnable) is a preferred choice for potentially blocking operations, since you actually want to start a new program, the simplest solution is to use QProcess, maybe with its own static method [`startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1).

Comment: Awesome, you were absolutely right about that PyQt believing the labels were actually hidden/showing when they actually weren't, this was proven by `print(self.label.isVisible())` which was super helpful.

I ended up going a route like this if in the future anyone has interest in doing the same:
`self.process = QProcess(); self.process.finished.connect(self.function_to_run_after_process); self.process.start(cmd_line arg)`

Thank you so much @musicmante!